# is there a way to display different information in different mode using fullcalendar.js?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

wondering if there's a way to display different information in different mode of fullcalendar

for example:
in monthly mode: title: 'short title', description showing as tooltips.
in weekly mode: title: 'long title' and description is showing under the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a similar question and would like to post that answer to my own question.
Basically, instead asking "different mode", I guess I should change it to "different view", and yes, the fullcalendar supports element rendering for different view, here is the example by using the eventAfterRender and put a condition when it's in daily view

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function (event, element) { ... },
    viewRender: function (view, element) { ... }, 
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        if ($('.fc-basicDay-view').length > 0) {
            $('.cl').each(function (i, item) {
                var title = item.title;
                item.innerText = item.innerText + ' - ' + item.title;
                $(this).css('font-size', '14px');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

credit to the following post:
[FullCalendar - Changing the text in the basicDay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978652/fullcalendar-changing-the-text-in-the-basicday-view)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the following code.. in full calender..

```
{
  month: 'MMMM yyyy',                             // September 2009
  week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", // Sep 7 - 13 2009
  day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'                  // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
}
```

Here you can format your title differently in different views.

Hopes that's your answer.

for further detail you can also read

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/

Comment: tks for the reply, however, this is just for date format, i was asking that if it's possible to add different contents in different mode, i.e. just title in monthly view, title and description in weekly view and title, description and detail contents in day view